# Creating a section of white background over a full-bleed background

Tags: html, css

I'm building a photography site using a builder called "photodeck" for a business.

The issue comes that the builder doesn't allow for me to create a background behind the menu and logo, so I have to do this through editing the theme CSS and HTML - I'm a coding rookie and after a lot of experimentation I cannot get it to work.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/gknowl/pen/PeJbOE  (For both CSS and HTML)

HTML (So I could post the codepen link) :

```html
<pd-page>
  <pd-block id="navib" class="dont_overlap">
    <pd-component id="logo" type="logo_text" />
    <div id="navlinks">
      <pd-component id="menu" type="menu" />
      <pd-component id="local" type="locale_switcher" />
    </div>
  </pd-block>
  <pd-component id="hdtxt" type="text" class="dont_overlap" />
  <div id="title_and_main_content_wrapper">
    <div id="main_block">
      <pd-component id="mainc" type="main_content" />
      <pd-component id="commt" type="comments" />
      <pd-component id="searc" type="search" drawer="duration:0.3,rotate_alt_content:90,init_state:closed,alt_content_pos:center,alt_content:,effect:slide_from_right" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <pd-block id="footer" class="reserved_height dont_overlap">
    <pd-component id="fttxt" type="text" />
    <pd-component id="links" type="external_links" />
  </pd-block>
  <pd-component id="pwrdb" type="poweredby" />
</pd-page>
```

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba5wS.jpg (The part above the green bar I'd like to have a light grey background)

Bonus: If anyone can help me out with making the logo bigger as well that would be a great help, the builder limits the size to the size pictured

I apologise if this is too basic, or if this is far too obvious - however I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well your builder HTML markup is rendering in codepen so I am just gonna try to give you suggestions where you can make changes to get the desired result.

For making the logo bigger. Add increased width and height in this class. For responsiveness also change the width for same class in different media queries as well.

```
#ws_page #component_logo {
  width: //As per need;
  height: //As per need
}
```

For nav background colour try in this:

```
#ws_page #block_navib {
  background: #ccc;
}
```